# Why I can't create an index on temporary table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

First I created a temporary table

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TMP ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
SELECT *
FROM A
```

then

```
INSERT INTO TMP
SELECT *
FROM B

COMMIT
```

finally

```
CREATE INDEX IDX ON TMP (COLA, COLB, COLC);
```

Upon creating the index, I got the following error

> ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use

I followd these steps in the same session.

What I want to do(with temporary table) is

1. Disable/Drop index
2. Insert large data
3. Enable/Create index

How can I acheive this?

Comment: You may need to do a commit after the `insert`.

Comment: still gettting the same error...

Comment: The table is permanent and so its index should be permanent as well.

Answer (score 3):

> ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use
>
> This error occurs when it is tried to perform a DDL on a global temporary table with on commit preserve rows when the session trying to do the DDL has already made a DML on the table.
>       In order to do a DDL, the table must first be either truncated or the session must be exited.

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/err/ora_14452.html

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit to being surprised by this. The only solution I have come up with so far is to re-establish the session

```
SQL> drop table tmp;

Table dropped.

SQL> 
SQL> CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TMP ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
  2  SELECT *
  3  FROM emp
  4  ;

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO TMP
  2  SELECT *
  3  FROM emp
  4  ;

14 rows created.

SQL> 
SQL> COMMIT
  2  ;

Commit complete.

SQL> 
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> 
SQL> CREATE INDEX IDX ON TMP (empno);

Index created.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert lines into a temp table it gets locked and the index can't be created.
You should create the index before inserting the data:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS  AS
        SELECT *
          FROM scott.dept;
```

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON
    tmp (deptno);
```

```
ora-14452: tentativa de criar, alterar ou eliminar um índice em uma tabela temporária que já está sendo usada
14452. 00000 -  "attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create, alter or drop an index on temporary
           table which is already in use.
*Action:   All the sessions using the session-specific temporary table have
           to truncate table and all the transactions using transaction
           specific temporary table have to end their transactions.
```

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tmp;

Table TMP truncado.

CREATE INDEX idx ON tmp (deptno); 

Index idx criado.

INSERT INTO tmp
    SELECT *
      FROM scott.dept;

4 linhas inserido.

COMMIT;

Commit concluído.
```